# How to count files and lines in a project using Ant?

Tags: ant, metrics

I would like to quickly generate the following metrics in a local project using **Ant**:

- count total lines in all files
- total lines per file type

Example:

> Total **1337** files and **44** folders (**658462** lines):
>
> - **xxx** .png files (**0** lines)
> - **xxx** .jpg files (**0** lines)
> - **xxx** .txt files (**xxxx** lines)
> - **xxx** .js files (**xxx** lines)

and so on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

how about a target that calls [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)?

If you were on a Unix system, this would look like:

```
 <target name="run-cloc">
   <exec dir="." executable="perl">
     <arg value="${cloc.path}"/>
      <arg value="${src.dir}"/>
   </exec>
 </target>
```

Here `cloc.path` is the full path to the CLOC Perl script.

If you were on Windows, the target changes to use the pre-built exe instead (so `cloc.path` is the full path to the CLOC exe):

```
 <target name="run-cloc">
   <exec dir="." executable="${cloc.path}">
     <arg value="${src.dir}"/>
   </exec>
 </target>
```

Comment: I've modified my answer to include a sample

Comment: Thank you I'll try it ASAP and report the results here.

Comment: @adnan-doric, did you get a chance to try this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mixed Unix/Windows environment (e.g., Jenkins), the following will work:

```
<target name="cloc" description="Generate code metrics.">

    <exec searchpath="true" executable="cloc">
        <arg value="--by-file" />
        <arg value="--xml" />
        <arg value="--out=${cloc.report.dir}/cloc.xml" />
        <arg value="${src.dir}" />
    </exec>

</target>
```

On Windows, rename the executable (e.g., cloc-1.64.exe to cloc.exe) and add the location to your Windows PATH variable (e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\cloc\`).

On Unix, cloc typically installs to `/usr/bin`, which is already in the path.

As long as you can invoke the command using "`cloc`" on both environments, the above Ant target will work on both platforms without modifications.